# Faster way to select rows in Pandas and put them into a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 6 million rows, currently I am doing the following:

```
symbol = 'BPCL'
rows=[]
start = time.time()
times = fut_df.timestamp.tolist()
for t in times:
    s_df = fut_df[fut_df['timestamp'] == t]
    s_df.sort_values('expiry', inplace=True)
    if len(s_df) > 0:
        # s_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        # count += 1
        while len(s_df) < 3:
            s_df.loc[len(s_df)] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        rows.append([symbol, t,
                     s_df['close_under'].iloc[0], 
                     s_df['contractname'].iloc[0], s_df['close'].iloc[0],
                     s_df['contractname'].iloc[1], s_df['close'].iloc[1], 
                     s_df['contractname'].iloc[2], s_df['close'].iloc[2])
print(time.time() - start)
```

This doesn't seem very efficient to me. And takes a lot of time. Is there a more pandas/pythonic way to do this? I think `lambda` might work faster or `map`?

example of `fut_df`:

```
        contractname           timestamp   close     bid     ask  close_under  bid_under  ask_under     expiry
7485094  BPCL20MAYFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:52  372.20  371.85  372.75       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-05-01
7485095  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:52  371.50  371.45  373.65       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-04-01
7485096  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:52  371.50  371.05  373.65       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-04-01
7485097  BPCL20MAYFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:53  372.20  371.85  372.75       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-05-01
7485098  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:53  371.50  371.05  373.65       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-04-01
7485099  BPCL20MAYFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:54  372.20  372.00  372.70       371.00     371.00      371.9 2020-05-01
7485100  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:54  371.50  371.05  373.65       371.00     371.00      371.9 2020-04-01
7485101  BPCL20MAYFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:55  372.20  372.00  372.70       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-05-01
7485102  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:55  371.50  371.35  373.65       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-04-01
7485103  BPCL20JUNFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:56  372.45  372.15  373.95       371.90     371.85      371.9 2020-06-01
7485104  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:56  371.50  371.05  373.65       371.90     371.85      371.9 2020-04-01
7485105  BPCL20MAYFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:56  372.70  372.00  372.75       371.90     371.85      371.9 2020-05-01
7485106  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:57  371.50  371.10  373.65       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-04-01
7485107  BPCL20MAYFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:57  372.70  372.00  372.75       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-05-01
7485108  BPCL20APRFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:58  371.50  371.40  373.65       371.90     371.85      371.9 2020-04-01
7485109  BPCL20MAYFUT 2020-04-30 15:29:59  372.70  372.00  372.75       371.85     371.85      371.9 2020-05-01
```

expected output after rows are made I will be putting them into a dataframe:

```
symbol timestamp close_under m1 m1_close m2 m2_close m3 m3_close

BPCL 2020-04-30 15:29:52 371.85 BPCL20APRFUT 371.50  BPCL20MAYFUT 372.20 0 0
```

The current code is taking approx 28 hours to go through the dataframe. How can I speed this up? I am using `multiprocessing/concurrent.futures` to go through multiple files at once.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'times'

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you could condense the problem to a single feature, e.g. "close"ing-price and provide a sample with less features but more data points to test. As a general hint you could try to avoide the loops alltogether.

Comment: @Andreas changed it. It was supposed to be `timestamp`

Comment: thank you, but it seems `symbol` isn't defined as well. Please note that pandas can provide much more performance if you try to use native methods. In your case I would try to use groupby. I can show you a small example if you could provide a sample that multiple input rows but only has 2 result rows.

Comment: @Andreas yes avoiding the loop would be best, Still trying to wrap my head around how to vectorize the operation. I am add more data points and reducing the features.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
d = {'close_under':'first','close':'last','bid':'first'}
df = fut_df.groupby(['contractname', 'timestamp']).aggregate(d)
```

out:

```
                        close_under  close     bid
contractname timestamp                            
2020-04-30   15:29:52        371.85  371.5  371.85
             15:29:53        371.85  371.5  371.85
             15:29:54        371.00  371.5  372.00
             15:29:55        371.85  371.5  372.00
             15:29:56        371.90  372.7  372.15
             15:29:57        371.85  372.7  371.10
             15:29:58        371.90  371.5  371.40
             15:29:59        371.85  372.7  372.00
```